# Spyder newbie can't see generated chart

Tags: python, spyder, python-ggplot

I am very new to Spyder.  I've found it useful but one thing that continues to confuse me is working with graphs and charts.  Below is work-in-progress code building toward showing a bar chart showing subway useage on rainy and dry days.  At this point I'm simply trying to see rainy days (I am not much of a programmer so I proceed by baby steps).  The IPython console returns

```
runfile('C:/Users/Brian/Dropbox/Data_Science_Course/Final Intro Data Science Project/rainy vs dry bar chart.py', wdir='C:/Users/Brian/Dropbox/Data_Science_Course/Final Intro Data Science Project')
```

So it looks like it has at least run.  However, I CANNOT find how to actually view the graph.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)

from ggplot import *

def show_rainy_days():

    subway_data_df = pd.read_csv('/home/brian/Dropbox/Data_Science_Course/Final Intro Data Science Project/turnstile_weather_v3_test.csv')

    rainy_days_df = subway_data_df[subway_data_df.rain == 1]

    dry_days_df = subway_data_df[subway_data_df.rain == 0]

    print rainy_days_df.mean()['ENTRIESn']

    print dry_days_df.mean()['ENTRIESn']

    print ggplot(rainy_days_df, aes('UNIT', 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_bar(stat='bar') + ggtitle('Rainy Day Subway Useage') + xlab('Stations on Rainy Days') + ylab('Average Riders')
```

What Spyder settings am I missing or what else am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `show_rainy_days` function at the end of your file, like this:

```
def show_rainy_days():
    ...
    ggplot(rainy_days_df, aes('UNIT', 'ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_bar(stat='bar') + ggtitle('Rainy Day Subway Useage') + xlab('Stations on Rainy Days') + ylab('Average Riders')


show_rainy_days()
```

That's why your code is not doing anything :-)

**Note**: The three dots I wrote above (before the last `ggplot` command) mean that everything is the same as in your code above. The only thing that I changed is removing `print` before `ggplot` because that's not needed.

Comment: @BrianM I'm really glad to hear it! Then please mark the question as answered by clicking on the green check sign above :-)